# To obtain operating privileges after the 2 year grace

Tags: united-states, license

I have been under medically supervised treatment for the past few years.  I have been on heavy meds.  I presently am showing signs of improvement from cognitive issues which were troubling me.  I discovered that my license is expired past the two year renewal period.  Is there any way that my license can be salvaged?

Comment: Congratulations on your recovery! You'll need to tell us which country you're in, since this depends on local laws.

Comment: Ah, since you're subject to the FCC then: This [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/amateurradio/comments/a19qdg/fcc_renewal_after_grace_period/) seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

To reclaim a license expired more than 2 years one must retake element 2 (Technician).  If you were a General or Advanced previously, you will be granted General privileges.  If you were an Amateur Extra, you will be granted Extra privileges.

If you were previously licensed as a Tech then not really, because you have to retake the Tech and will be granted Tech privileges.  Once you do this however, you can request your old call sign as a vanity and get it back that way.